Automatically rename uploaded files in Google Form
I have a google form for a small radio station for presenters to upload their shows.
In the form they fill out the broadcast date, presenter name, show name, a few other bits of information, and then they upload the audio, an image, and the tracklist (text file).
I want the audio, image and text files to be renamed in this format "YYYYMMDD PresenterName ShowName"
I've been trying to create a script to do this, however I'm only just learning about how to do this and can't get it working.
This is what I've used and isn't working:
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  
  // Define your indexes here
  var dateIndex = 1;
  var presenterNameIndex = 3;
  var showNameIndex = 4;
  var fileUploadIndices = [9, 10, 14]; // Example indices for file upload questions
  
  // Get the latest response
  var latestResponseIndex = responses.length - 1;
  var latestResponse = responses[latestResponseIndex];
  
  // Get date, presenter name, and show name from form responses
  var date = latestResponse.getItemResponses()[dateIndex].getResponse();
  var presenterName = latestResponse.getItemResponses()[presenterNameIndex].getResponse();
  var showName = latestResponse.getItemResponses()[showNameIndex].getResponse();
  
  // Format the date as YYYYMMDD
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyyMMdd');
  
  // Construct the desired file name
  var fileName = formattedDate + ' ' + presenterName + ' ' + showName;
  
  // Loop through file upload questions and rename files
  fileUploadIndices.forEach(function(index) {
    var fileId = latestResponse.getItemResponses()[index].getResponse();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    
    // Append the filename with the original file's extension
    var originalFileName = file.getName();
    var extension = originalFileName.substr(originalFileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    var newFileName = fileName + extension;
    
    // Rename the file
    file.setName(newFileName);
  });
}

It returns this error:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.
at unknown function
at myFunction(Code:27:21)

Thanks for any help.

I don't know these objects: how are you importing DriveApp? Does it need initialising first / how are you initialising it?

There's nothing wrong with your code; i've run your it (adjusted for my own Form) and it is OK. The most likely problem is that your file indexes are not [9, 10, 14]. When looking at responses, indexes are the equivalent of the question number. Would you please review your Form and confirm that the upload questions are the ninth, tenth and fourteenth question respectively. You could insert a new line Logger.log("the file id = "+fileId) after var fileId= and before var file = and report on the value reported.
